# Call a vb.net function stored in an access table

Tags: vb.net

I stored some function's names in an Access table, an I would like to execute them in vb.net, I can't find the way to do it, maybe someone know how to do it.

```
public sub KeyDatesProcess()
   Dim sqlQuery As String
   Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
   Dim rs As OleDbDataReader

   Dim listForStartDates As List(Of CriticalDates)
   Dim listForFinishDates As List(Of CriticalDates)

  Try
      sqlQuery = "select * from wbs_l2"

      cmd = New OleDbCommand With {
          .Connection = connection,
          .CommandText = sqlQuery
      }

      rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      Do While rs.Read
          Debug.Print(rs(0) & " " & rs(3))
          listForStartDates = CallByName(rs(6).ToString) 'this field contains a function
          listForFinishDates = CallByName(rs(7).ToString) 'this field contains a function
      Loop
  Catch ex As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
  End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Basic .net - Call Procedure from a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098130/visual-basic-net-call-procedure-from-a-variable-name)

Comment: Do you intend to overwrite the 2 lists on each iteration of your `Do While`?

Comment: The connection stays open as long as reader is open. If you are calling functions while holding the connection open this is a really long time to hold a connection open. Dump your data to a DataTable and close and dispose your connection. Then loop through the datarows.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to fill those collection with data that comes from the function.